# " Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException " error is occured when i execute the following code.

Tags: java, selenium

I wrote a code in webdriver for getting the window id of tab window but code throws a exception . 
    " Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException "  error is occured when i execute the following code.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
public class web_windows {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.icicibank.com/");
        Set<String> winids = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> iterate = winids.iterator();

        System.out.println(iterate.next());

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='footer_container']/p/a[1]")).click();
        winids = driver.getWindowHandles();
        iterate = winids.iterator();
        String firstwindow = iterate.next(); // window id of main window

        String tabwindow = iterate.next();  // window id of tabbed window
        // main tab 
        System.out.println(firstwindow);
        // tabbed window
        System.out.println(tabwindow);





    }

}
```

After execting above code following error is coming:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$LinkedHashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
    at web_windows.main(web_windows.java:
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to check if it exists before you access it

```
while(iterate.hasNext()){
String firstwindow = iterate.next();
}
```

Documentation states that

`boolean hasNext()`

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
>
> Returns:
>   true if the iteration has more elements

`iterate.next()`

> Throws:
>   NoSuchElementException - if the iteration has no more elements

This is what happens in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your winids is empty, most likely your xpath is wrong, without having a look at the webpage I suggest you test your xpath, maybe using jquery and a javascript console in your browser